# How to pass check box values in AngularJS using ng-model in conjunction with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I have a page which offers users the ability to search for articles by entering a search term and filter the results if required.

The filters initially contained multiple select box with values been fetched from ajax call and the selected values been sent back using ng-model. It was working fine.

Now the requirement is to convert multiple select box into checkboxes and I have managed to create the checkbox.

I am facing issues when users enter a search query and selects one of the checkboxes, I am not able to get the selected checkbox value in app.js to filter the results.

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <h3 class="m0 pb-lg">Filters</h3>
    <div class="form-group mb-xl">
         <form method="get" ng-controller="SearchController as form" class="form-horizontal">
            <label class="control-label mb">By Type of Study</label><br><label class="checkbox-inline c-checkbox" ng-repeat="s in form.typeOfStudies">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.typeOfStudy" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
                <span class="fa fa-check"></span>{{s}}</input>
            </label>
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The app.js contains:

```
 $scope.getById = function (id) {
           if (id.typeOfStudy){
            $.each(id.typeOfStudy, function() {
                    if (count < id.typeOfStudy.length) {
                        count++;
                        qTypeOfStudy += "'" + this + "',";
                    }
                    else if (count == id.typeOfStudy.length) {
                        qTypeOfStudy += "'" + this + "'";
                    }
            })
        }
  }
```

getById is been passed on form submission of main text in the search bar on the page.

Comment: you can use ng-click to value into controller

Comment: can you write plunker?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Shohel, can you please share an example or a link?

Comment: I can try but its part of huge application, so I'll try my best to create one.

Comment: Mixing JQuery and Angular is really hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I am using some value from `ng-repeat` list to be an id, you can have something you have in `s in form.typeOfStudies`.
something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="modelList in modelsLists">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.ids[modelList.id]" id="{{modelList.id}}"/>
</div>
```

Initialize in JS:

```
$scope.selection = {
        ids: {}
    };
```

and check for checkbox:

```
if($scope.selection.ids[id]){
    // do something
}
```